# Strict maximums and minimums of a function

Tags: real-analysis

The set of points where an arbitrary function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined in a set $X \subset \mathbb{R^m}$ admits a strict maximum or minimum is enumerable.

Proof:
Let $E \subset X$ be a dense enumerable subset and  If $A$ is the set of points where f attains a strict local maximum,  then for each point $x \in A$ that is a strict maximum of $f$, choose $e_{x} \in E$ and $r_{x} \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $|e_{x} - x| <r_{x}$ and $y \in B(e_{x}; r_{x}) - \{x\} \Rightarrow f(y) < f(x)$. Define the application  $g:A \to E \times \mathbb {Q}$ such that $x \mapsto (e_{x}, r_{x})$.

I have done this demonstration up to this point, but I just need to prove that $g$ is injective. Could someone give me any suggestions to do this, please.

Answer (score 1):

What's left is to write down what you've got!

Let $x,y∈X$ such that $g(x)=g(y)\Leftrightarrow e_x=e_y∧r_x=r_y$. So, $y\in B(e_x,r_x)$ and $x∈ B(e_y,r_y)$. Supposing that $x≠y$, we have that $x\in B(e_y,y)-\{y\}$, so $f(x)<f(y)$ and $y\in B(e_x,r_x)-\{x\}$, so $f(y)<f(x)$, a contradiction. So, $x=y$ and, hence, $g$ is injective and, hence, $A$ is countable.